Does rsync's delta-transfer mean it will not transfer identical files OR transfer the change in two similar files
From rsync's manpage:

It is famous for its delta-transfer algorithm, which reduces the amount of data sent over the network by sending only the differences between the source files and the existing files in the destination...
Rsync finds files that need to be transferred using a lqquick checkrq algorithm (by default) that looks for files that have changed in size or in last-modified time. Any changes in the other preserved attributes (as requested by options) are made on the destination file directly when the quick check indicates that the file's data does not need to be updated.

Does delta-transfer "differences between the source files and the existing files in the destination" mean:

source/file and dest/file are identical files, as computed by timestamp or checksum, so it is not transferred
along with 1, source/file and dest/file are close in binary diff, so only the difference between the files is sent

Why does't rsync use delta-transfer for local files? says rsync doesn't use delta-transfer for local files (in my case, between /home and /media). But if I leave off --no-W or use -W, will it still not transfer identical files?

The delta transfer is an optimisation that can speed up repeated copies across a network of changed files.
It works by reading the source file with one process and reading the destination file with another process, and then comparing them in a such a way that the sender only needs to transmit blocks of data that are not already present at the destination.
If you consider copying between two parts of a local filesystem, you would need to read both files in their entirety in order to work out what to write to the destination. In the general situation a complete read followed by a partial write would be more efficiently replaced by a complete write. (This doesn't account for storage media where reading is significantly faster than writing, but the algorithm assumes a general situation.)
There is another optimisation that is nothing to do with the delta transfer, whereby rsync assumes that a file of the same relative name, size and modification timestamp on the source and destination is probably the same file, and avoids processing it at all. Pretty much the only time this breaks is if you have an application that resets a file's modification time - and very very few applications do that.
Almost always, not telling rsync how to copy a file leads to the most efficient way of copying it. Just remember to include the --times (-t) flag.

I see, so delta transfer is distinct from timestamp/size check.
